# Meaning of int a[10]; int *p = a+9;

Tags: c

I am currently trying to understand pointers in C but I am having a hard time understanding this code:

```
int a[10]; 
int *p = a+9;
while ( p > a )
    *p-- = (int)(p-a);
```

I understand the code to some degree. I can see that an array with 10 integer elements is created then a pointer variable to type `int` is declared. (But I don't understand what `a+9` means: does this change the value of the array?).

It would be very helpful if someone could explain this step by step, since I am new to pointers in C.

Comment: `*p-- = (int)(p-a);` is **wrong** (it's *undefined behaviour*). You both change and use `p` within the same expression (technically without an intervening sequence point).

Comment: `a+9` is the same as `&a[9]`.  It's a pointer to the last element of `a`.  You should read up on pointer addition (i.e., the sum of a pointer and an integer).

Comment: Also take note of the comment by @pmg.  C does not specify whether you will get the old or new value of `p` in `(p-a)`.  One compiler may give you the old value while another may give you the new value.  Both would be correct implementations.  In other words, you should never write code that depends on the evaluation order.

Comment: @pmg: Now, you see, if you are going to use “technically,” then technically, you ought to get it right. Technically, this trigger for undefined behavior is that a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to another side effect or a value computation on the same object. If there is sequencing, this trigger does not apply, even if the sequencing is less than a full sequence point. One could be sequenced before the other or there could be unspecified sequencing.

Comment: Does `1+2` change the value of 1?

Comment: Re "*does this change the value of the array"*", Arrays don't have a value. They have elements, I suppose, but it's a stretch to call its elements its value. So no, it doesn't change its value since it doesn't have one.

Answer (score 0):

When used in an expression<sup>1</sup>, the name of an array in C, 'decays' to a pointer to its first element. Thus, in the expression `a + 9`, the `a` is equivalent to an `int*` variable that has the value of `&a[0]`.

Also, pointer arithmetic works in units of the pointed-to type; so, adding `9` to `&a[0]` means that you get the address of `a[9]` – the last element of the array. So, overall, the `p = a + 9` expression assigns the address of the array's last element to the `p` pointer (but it does *not* change anything in that array).

The subsequent `while` loop, however, *does* change the values of the array's elements, setting each to the value of its position (the result of the `p - a` expression) and decrementing the address in `p` by the size of an `int`. *(Well, that what it's probably **intended** to do; but, as mentioned in the comments, the use of such "unsequenced operations" – i.e. the use of `p--` and `p - a` in the same statement – is actually undefined behaviour because, in this case, the C Standard does not dictate which of those two expressions should be evaluated first.)*

To avoid that undefined behaviour, the code should be written to use an *explicit* intermediate, like this:

```c
int main()
{
    int a[10];
    int* p = a + 9;
    while (p > a) {
        int n = (int)(p - a); // Get the value FIRST ...
        *p-- = n;             // ... only THEN assign it
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> There two exceptions: when that array name is used as the operand of a `sizeof` operator or of the unary `&` (address of) operator.

Answer (score 0):

---

```
int a[10];
```

This declares an array on e.g. the stack. `a` represents the starting address of the array. The declaration tells the compiler that `a` will hold 10 integers. C assumes you know what you are doing so it is up to you to keep yourself in that range.

---

```
int *p = a+9;
```

p is declared a pointer e.g. like a RL street address. When you add an offset to `a` an offset is added to the address `a`. The compiler converts the offset like `+5` to bytes `+5*sizeof(int)` so you don't need to think about that, so your `p` pointer is now pointing inside the array at offset 9 - which is the last int in the array `a` since index starts at 0 in C.

---

```
while( p > a )
```

The condition says that do this while the address of what `p` is pointing to is larger than the address where `a` is.

---

```
*p-- = (int)(p-a);
```

here the value what `p` points to is overwritten with a crude(1) subtraction between current `p` and starting address `a` before the pointer p is decremented.

(1) Undefined Behavior

Comment: crude, as i said